# Make the headers in /tour ids instead of classes

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Just tried to link to a specific section in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to my dismay, the sections are all like:

```
<div class="about-offtopic">
...
</div>
```

Can this class be changed to be an id instead so we can use anchors, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tour#offtopic

Comment: Related MSE feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173223/about-pages-need-navigation-links

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the edit - feeling a bit bleary-eyed this morning!